# "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused" when using Travis CI with Laravel/Codeception

Tags: travis-ci

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with Codeception for acceptance testing, and this keeps happening:

```
1) TestCest: Home
 Test  tests/acceptance/TestCest.php:home

  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  

Scenario Steps:
 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests/acceptance/TestCest.php:6
```

Rarely is just seems to work randomly, but for the most part it errors. I've spent a while on this and would love a permanent fix.

some relevant files:

.travis.yml

```
language: php
sudo: false
dist: trusty
cache: false

php:
  - 7.2.3

services:
  - mysql

before_install:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;'

install:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - npm i -g npm
  - npm install

before_script:
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan migrate --no-interaction -vvv
  - php artisan serve --env=testing --no-ansi --no-interaction --port=8888 --host=localhost &

script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --no-ansi --no-interaction
```

.env.travis

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=base64:dHJA2G0xXnUEP82ota/J4WBnXSYGP9VHRBl6fvclfjk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8888

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

I replaced

```
php artisan serve --env=testing --no-ansi --no-interaction --port=8888 --host=localhost &
```

with

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8888 -t ./public/ &
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Vanilla (Core) PHP when I used CURL. My code was connecting to the other computer in the local network.

CURL code was correct and there was no problem with it.

Constantly I got this error:
**Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused**

Solution to this problem was to open port **8888** on Apache on my computer. Since I'm using *Ubuntu 16.04* I did this in file:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Here I have added this line to ports file:

```
Listen 8888
```

After this I did Apache restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```